# angularjs ui-sref not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

In my angular app i am using

```
<a data-ui-sref="app.page({ page: 'splitsale', child: null })">test</a>
```

for switching screens. But it does not work in Firefox however its working fine in chrome.

Why?

Comment: What is the state's name? And also are page and child stateParams?

Comment: its page with name splitesale.

Comment: why don't you use data-ui-sref="splitsale" ??

Comment: Thanks. I got solution myself. I am using <a> tag inside <button> tag that's why its not working.